# How do I change a string column into a bigint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, migration

In rails migration. How do I change a string type column to a bigint?

I  have:

```
t.change :ip_number_from, :integer, :limit => 8
```

I get:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "ip_number_from" cannot be cast to type bigint
```

I even tried with the 2 alternatives:

```
change_column :ip_to_countries, :ip_number_from, :integer, :limit => 8
change_column :ip_to_countries, :ip_number_from, :bigint
```

Still the same error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Postgres is telling you that there is existing data in that column which it doesn't know how to convert, so it needs an ALTER statement which supplies a USING clause for the column to specify how to cast existing values.

Unfortunately, you're going to need to drop down the database-specific code to accomplish this, or use something similar to the solution suggested here:

http://webjazz.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/how-to-alter-columns-in-postgresql.html

Edit: Here's how you might do it directly in SQL in your migration:

```
execute <<-SQL
  ALTER TABLE ip_to_countries
  ALTER COLUMN ip_number_from TYPE bigint USING ip_number_from::bigint
SQL
```

Comment: In the migration file, this works too: `IpToCountry.connection.execute('alter table ip_to_countries alter ip_number_from type bigint using ip_number_from::bigint;')`

Answer (score 3):

What is in your ip_number_from column?

In any case, I would probably:

- create a new column of type bigint,
- copy the data from ip_number_from to new_column manually through rails console or a rake task,
- drop the original ip_number_from column
- rename new_column to ip_number_from

Or you could drop down to SQL, like mjtko suggested, but I'm not sure it will be any easier.

#### Update

I looked up what Yule is suggesting. I think it would be a bit dangerous to do all of this in one migration, since you can't really check if the casting/copying of data was successful. If you did want to do it in one migration, in your case it would look something like this:

```
def up
  add_column :table, :new_column, :bigint
  Model.reset_column_information
  Model.all.each do |m|
    m.update_attribute :new_column, Model.bigint_from_ip_number_from(m)
  end
  drop_column :table, :ip_number_from
  rename_column :table, :new_column, :ip_number_from
end
```

You should also then add a corresponding down migration.

You can always split this up in multiple migrations and check the progress/success as you go.

Comment: If you take this approach, I'd put it in the migration, rather than console/other rake task. It needs to be consistent if DB was to be created from migrations

Comment: This is a sensible approach if total database independence is your aim, but isn't the most efficient of solutions IMHO.

Comment: I agree that it's not the most efficient way. Do you know what happens with your migration if there is a string like "foobar" in ip_number_from? I'm genuinely curious, I have no idea. Does it just fail and rollback? Or is the new ip_number_from null?

Comment: Thanks I found this approach to be the most maintainable since if you do SQL directly into your database you lose the migration history and forever have to remember to do this one tweak in the SQL console. Taking the time to make a good migration ensures continuity and a tested fix for production and colleagues' environments.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently read - but don't remember where - that you can't cast "string" columns to "int" columns but you can do the contrary. The cast from "int" to "string" is an irreversible migration operation.

I'll search the document where I read that and edit my post when I'll find it.

If you can, the easiest thing to do would be what Jure Triglav is suggesting. (He posted his answer before mine but I was suggesting the same thing ;) ).

[Edit] I found back where I read that: [Irreversible Migration tuto](http://ariejan.net/2008/05/06/the-migration-that-cannot-be-undone-irreversible-migration).

Comment: Not being able to cast from strings to integers is not true of all DBMS, I think that article was merely using that kind of operation as an example. :)

Answer (score -1):

`change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'TYPE bigint USING CAST(column_name AS TYPE bigint)'`

Comment: Above not working for rails 7 I used the below mentioned and works 

```change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'bigint USING CAST(column_name AS bigint)'```