# change an integer to bigint in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, command-line, migration, heroku-postgres

I need to change my table integers to BIGINT's
I am using `RoR` and `SQLLite`.

How can I modify existing table fields from `Int` to `BigInt` through command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a migration. Here's a link to the docs: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Basically, you need to run:

```
rails g migration change_your_column_to_bigint
```

and add this code to the migration new migration file:

```
def up
  execute <<-SQL
    ALTER TABLE ip_to_countries
    ALTER COLUMN your_column TYPE bigint USING your_column::bigint
  SQL
end
```

For the record, I stole this from here: [How do I change a string column into a bigint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380399/how-do-i-change-a-string-column-into-a-bigint), but didn't mark it as duplicate because it involves converting a string column.

now I am getting this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "ALTER": syntax error:     ALTER TABLE posts
    ALTER COLUMN mileage TYPE bigint USING mileage::bigint
C:/Sites/jeepjig/db/migrate/20150315145856_change_mileage_to_bigint.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "ALTER": syntax error:     ALTER TABL
    ALTER COLUMN mileage TYPE bigint USING mileage::bigint
C:/Sites/jeepjig/db/migrate/20150315145856_change_mileage_to_bigint.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
SQLite3::SQLException: near "ALTER": syntax error
C:/Sites/jeepjig/db/migrate/20150315145856_change_mileage_to_bigint.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

after running this

```
class ChangeMileageToBigint < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  execute <<-SQL
    ALTER TABLE posts
    ALTER COLUMN mileage TYPE bigint USING mileage::bigint
  SQL
end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the SQL statement ..any idea ?